# Retain Initial XML Comments when file is created using Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

My Python code pulls below XML file stored in SQL Server and with Print(result) statement code shows same XML file stored in SQL Server.

XML File in SQL Server:

```
<!-- Outside Comment -->
<xbrl xmlns='http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance'
      xmlns:xbrli='http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance'
      xmlns:link='http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase'
      xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
      xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
      xmlns:iso4217='http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217'
      xmlns:HelloWorld='http://xbrl.squarespace.com/HelloWorld'
      xsi:schemaLocation='
       '>
    <!-- Inside Comment -->
</xbrl>
```

But, when I write the output of Print(Results) to file, It strips the initial comment: `<!-- Outside Comment -->` and creates file with `<!-- Inside Comment -->` retained. I would like to know how to retain the `<!-- Outside Comment -->`

XML File Created:

```
<xbrl xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
      xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217"
      xmlns:HelloWorld="http://xbrl.squarespace.com/HelloWorld" xsi:schemaLocation="        ">
    <!-- Inside Comment -->
</xbrl>
```

Python Code:

```
from lxml import etree
print(r)
myXML = etree.XML(r)
XML_file = open("Output.xml", "wb")
XML_file.write(etree.tostring(myXML, pretty_print = True))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<!-- Outside Comment -->` is a sibling of the root element (represented by `myXML` in the code). It is not included in the output from `tostring(myXML)`.

But if you create an [`ElementTree`](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-elementtree-class) instance and write it to a file, it works. Replace the two last lines in your snippet with this line:

```
etree.ElementTree(myXML).write("Output.xml", pretty_print=True)
```